# Accessing rows in a 2d python list for calculating distance between values

Tags: python, list, distance

I have a list with a few hundred values which looks like this:

`(0.0021265099091875685, 0.0017700721644805513)
(0.0026319917728469086, 0.002632415013842871)`

I want to calculate the euclidean distance between each row.

The way I plan on calculating it is something like this:

```
sqrt(0.0021265099091875685 - 0.0026319917728469086)^2 + (0.0017700721644805513 -  0.002632415013842871)^2
```

I'm having trouble working out how I can access each value in order to do those calculations. If anyone has any ideas about doing this it would be very helpful. Thanks

EDIT: I'm pulling data from a MySQL db. Initially I had two lists, when printed out, a list would look like this:

`0.00212650990919
0.00263199177285
0.00332920813651
0.00268428300012
0.00245768768193`

I then created a new list by doing this:

```
someList = zip(list1 , list2)
```

which gave me the output I have above.

Comment: By between each row, you mean that for a list containing three rows, you'd like to calculate `d(1, 2), d(2, 3)` correct? Not `d(1, 2), d(2, 3), d(1, 3)`?

Comment: Yes you're correct, I'd want to use the former, not the latter.

Comment: So, I'm still not clear. Are we talking about two lists like so: `x_values = [1.0, 2.3, 4.5, ... ]` and `y_values = [3.4, 1.1, 0.3, ... ]` which becomes `someList = [(1.0, 3.4), (2.3, 1.1), (4.5, 0.3), ... ]` when `zip`ped?

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip:

```
l1=(0.0021265099091875685, 0.0017700721644805513)
l2=(0.0026319917728469086, 0.002632415013842871)
result=[(x-y)**(1/2) for x,y in zip(l1,l2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your data is going to be from your question. I am assuming your data to be as:

```
data = [
[(0.0021265099091875685, 0.0017700721644805513), (0.0026319917728469086, 0.002632415013842871)],
[(0.0021265099091875685, 0.0017700721644805513), (0.0026319917728469086, 0.002632415013842871)],
[(point-one), (point-two)],
...
]
```

This will then give you what you need:

```
[pow(sqrt(item[1][0] - item[0][0]), 2) + pow((item[1][1] -  item[0][1]), 2) for item in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list looks like this:

```
lst = [ ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)), ... ]
```

Then you can just do:

```
import math
distances = [ math.sqrt((p1[0]-p2[0])**2.0 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2.0) for p1, p2 in lst ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your list looks something like this...

```
xyz = [(0.0021265099091875685, 0.0017700721644805513), (0.0026319917728469086, 0.002632415013842871), ...]
```

You can also do...

```
For item in xyz:
    first_num = item[0]
    second_num = item[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks something like this:

```
points = [
    (a, b),
    (c, d),
    (e, f),
    ...
]
```

Then you might do something like this:

```
d = lambda x, y: ((y[0] - x[0]) ** 2 + (y[1] - x[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5
distances = [d(*pair) for pair in zip(points, points[1:])]
```

Comment: My data isn't defined that way actually. I had two lists, each which had a few hundred float values in them. I merged those two lists into one list like this:

    someList = zip(list1 , list2)

Comment: @user3157916: So once you merge the lists, using zip, they will look like the one I have?

Comment: Ah! Silly me. Bit of a brain fart there. Thank you for the help, this is what I needed!